# Need Help using inner joint in code ignitier

Tags: sql, codeigniter

Need help there any one know using inner joint with condition in code ignitier?

my code sql :

```
function call_detail()
    {
    $tSQL = "select a.Kode, b.name as Costumer, b.address, c.date, c.date1, f.subtotal, f.price from Table_1 a inner join Table_2 b on A.Kode = b.Kode inner join Table_3 c on A.Kode = c.kode inner join Table_4 d on c.Kode = d.Kode inner join Table_5 e on d.kode = e.Kode left join (select kodett, sum(quntity) as QTY, sum(Price) as Price from Table_3 where kodeAA is not null group by kodeAA) f on  c.Kode = F.kodeAA Where e.kode = 'OK' and c.date is null and c.kodeAA is null and c.kode = $Kode";

            $query = $this->db->query($tSQL);
            $query = $this->db->get();
            return $query->result();
}
```

There something wrong with my code? error say" Message: Undefined variable: Kode"

Answer (score 0):

use a.Kode instead of A.Kode

Maybe you can provide more details about your problem. Maybe you can provide your table and what u want to do with it.